# Is "How do I work with this S4 object" a legitimate question to tag with "S4"?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [s4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/s4) tag gets attached to a lot of questions, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53770227/subsetting-polygons-from-spatial-polygons-object-by-slot-s4/53811723#53811723), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54662137/get-xy-path-coordinates-of-letters-in-a-word) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54554485/how-to-subset-s4-list-with-5-csanno-elements) where the primary objective of the question is to perform some basic task (usually data extraction) on an S4 object (usually one defined in a specialist package). Users are often confused that S4 objects don't behave like `data.frame`s or similar.

My question is, should these actually have the [s4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/s4) tag? It feels like they shouldn't; by analogy, imagine if whenever a c++ user wanted to know how to do something with a classed object, that they tagged the question with `oop`. That would make the `oop` tag near-useless I would think.

If the prevailing opinion is that `S4` *is* an appropriate tag, then is there a good reference answer for a question along the lines of "I don't understand how to get the 'data' out of this weird S4 object. Help!" (I'm happy to write such a thing if it doesn't exist)

Comment: Imagine if every time someone wanted to know how to do something in C++ tagged  the question with [tag:c++]... Yes, that is how tags should be used.

Comment: Not familiar with R, but it appears that s4 is a valid tag, some one could be an expert in using the s4 OOP system in R, similarly one could be an expert in using classes in C++ maybe?  From the tag description it looks like there are multiple ways to do OOP in R and S4 is just one system?

Comment: I'm not saying the `s4` tag is completely invalid — there are lots of useful questions tagged with it. The problem is that there are many instances of "in package `foo`, I don't know how to work with this S4 object" — a general expert on S4 such as myself will be unable to help as it depends on how package `foo` was written, and posters generally need a lot of hand-holding to know which information they need to give to get an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend keeping [s4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/s4), but also adding [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) as the primary tag. This way, people who follow both tags can see it.

Comment: The questions are usually tagged with `r` as well, the problem is that knowledge of S4 is not generally helpful in answering these questions (or seeking them out, particularly) — what the poster needs is typically a tag related to their specific package.